# Matplotlib.pyplot.contourf: lines, or gaps between polygons?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, polygon, contour

I'm trying to plot a filled contour plot, but the edge of each polygon is white.

I've tried turning them of with `linewidth=0`, `linewidths=0`,`edgecolor=None` and a few others. I'm beginning to think it is a rounding-error type gap between the polygons, but I don't know. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's what I mean: bottom left and top right, made with

```
plt.contourf(X,Y,S,20,cmap=get_cmap('PiYG'),linewidths=0,edgecolor=None)
```

[image]

Comment: does it happen with some specific file format? Does the effect remain also if you save a file with high ppi?

Comment: also check the anti-aliasing features.  What version of mpl are you using?  Things related to this have received a bunch of attention recently.

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano it's not dependent on saving it even.

Comment: @tcaswell 1.0.1, I see it is on 1.2.1 now. Perhaps I should upgrade :)

Comment: Did upgrading fix your problems?

Comment: @tcaswell I ended up upgrading my whole operating system, now on 1.1.1r, will run it now.

Comment: @tcaswell 1.1.1rc actually, and it seems to fix it.

Comment: Can you write that as an answer and accept your own answer?  Upgrading the whole OS seems a tad drastic.  It isn't so bad to install mpl from source!

Comment: @tcaswell There were, of course, other reasons for my upgrade. But the upgrade was why I disappeared for a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to matplotlib 1.1.1rc (which comes ubuntu 12.04)

It now looks like (same function call) - you can see that the white edges have gone. The difference is more apparent in the vector graphics versions.

[image]